# Can't extract variables from Foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have an existing array that I want to extract the first name and last name out separately from a single full name field from and put each into their own variable. I've got the extraction to work the way I need, but I can't seem to retrieve the data once I'm out of the 'foreach' loop.

My array is this..

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => dduck
    [2] => Donald Duck
    [3] => donald@domain.com
)
```

When I run the foreach loop (below) the echo works. But if I echo the $firstName and $lastName outside of the loop, nothing is displayed....

This displays first and last name

```
foreach ($t_result as $name)
{
    preg_match('#^(\w+\.)?\s*([\'\’\w]+)\s+([\'\’\w]+)\s*(\w+\.?)?$#', $name, $results);
    $firstName = $results[2];
    $lastname = $results[3];
    echo $firstName . " " . $lastname;
}
```

This displays nothing

```
foreach ($t_result as $name)
{
    preg_match('#^(\w+\.)?\s*([\'\’\w]+)\s+([\'\’\w]+)\s*(\w+\.?)?$#', $name, $results);
    $firstName = $results[2];
    $lastname = $results[3];
}
echo $firstName . " " . $lastname;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried echo `$firstName` `$lastname` both in loop and after? Maybe it will give you some thoughts? And going deeper - `var_dump` these values both in loop and after it.

Comment: Yeah I did. After the loop displayed nothing. The 'fix' was to include an `if` statement inside the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not checking whether or not there is a match on your regex so for the array elements that do not match you are assigning `$firstName` and `$lastname` to undefined indexes.

The example array will not match on element `[3]` so those variables are more or less empty at the end of the loop making your echo outside of the loop not display anything.

You can try something like the following (wrapping the `preg_match` in an `if` statement):

```
foreach ($t_result as $name)
{
    if (preg_match("#^(\w+\.)?\s*(['\’\w]+)\s+(['\’\w]+)\s*(\w+\.?)?$#", $name, $results)) {
       $firstName = $results[2];
       $lastname = $results[3];
    }
}
echo $firstName . " " . $lastname;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the variables you're tring to return in an 'if' statement, otherwise the values are overwritten by subsequent loops:

```
$t_result = array(
    0 => 2,
    1 => 'dduck',
    2 => 'Donald Duck',
    3 => 'donald@domain.com',
);

foreach ( $t_result as $name ) {
    if ( preg_match( '#^(\w+\.)?\s*([\'\’\w]+)\s+([\'\’\w]+)\s*(\w+\.?)?$#', $name, $results ) ) {
        $firstName = $results[2];
        $lastname = $results[3];
    }
}

echo $firstName . " " . $lastname;
```